# How to check if the asset storage is null using ternary operator

Tags: php, laravel

i have problem regarding ternary operator, i want to check if the file is not exist in the storage or exist by using ternary operator. right now im using laravel blade. is there way to check the file name if exist on storage if not it will show not found.

Laravel Version: **5.7**

```
@foreach($get_latest_news_table as $latest_news_data)
  <a href="{{asset('storage/'.$latest_news_data->file_name)}}" target="_blank"><img class="d-block w-100" src="{{asset('storage/'.$latest_news_data->file_name)}}"></img> </a>
@endforeach
```

**Latest news data file name not exist:**

[image: Image not exist]

Thank you.

Comment: You mean this? https://laravel.com/docs/5.7/filesystem#retrieving-files

Comment: No @Loko i just want to check if the data is empty or not empty check my foreach loop.

Comment: Sorry I still don't get it. You say: `is there way to check the file name if exist on storage if not it will show not found` and my link gives functionality that  : `The exists method may be used to determine if a file exists on the disk:`. This is based on a file name.

Comment: yes no problem @Loko its okay .. thank you for your suggestion again sir.

Answer (score 3):

You can use `file_exists`

```
@foreach($get_latest_news_table as $latest_news_data)
  @if(!empty($latest_news_data->file_name) && file_exists(storage_path().'/'.$latest_news_data->file_name))
  <a href="{{asset('storage/'.$latest_news_data->file_name)}}" target="_blank"><img class="d-block w-100" src="{{asset('storage/'.$latest_news_data->file_name)}}"></img> </a>
  @endif
@endforeach
```

**Edit**:- You can check it with facade as well.

```
@if(Storage::exists($latest_news_data->file_name))
    <a href="{{asset('storage/'.$latest_news_data->file_name)}}" target="_blank"><img class="d-block w-100" src="{{asset('storage/'.$latest_news_data->file_name)}}"></img> </a>
 @endif
```

Comment: A better approach would be to use the Storage facade as Storage::exists($latest_news_data->file_name), or even as a method like $latest_news_data->file_exists(). This would enable the code to be more flexible just in case you decide to change the location of where the files are stored later.

Comment: Edited answer please check @AhmedShefeer

Comment: select the answer if it helped you.